# Why could Satan take the lives of Job's servants and Children but not touch Job's?

Tags: job

Why could Satan take the lives of Job's servants and Children but not touch Job's? I know in the text the answer is that God didn't give him permission to take Job's life, but God also didn't say you can do anything to him but take the lives of his family or servants either.

What biblical insights about God would help in understanding this?